Definition of free group action on a scheme
This may be an elementary question, but I didn't know what it means for a group action on a scheme to be free from the textbooks I read. I guess that at least for schemes locally of finite presentation, freeness means in the set of all closed points, the group action has no fixed point. Since for any ring, any group action will always fix the nilradical, which is prime if the affine scheme corresponding to the ring is irreducible. So I guess if the freeness is defined in the sense that it has totally no fixed point, then it will not make much sense. However, I am not sure whether this definition is correct or not, and I may need some help on that.
Better still, if one can give me a reference which talks about equivariant algebraic geometry (scheme theory), where the definition of the above is given, it will be greatly appreaciated.

That's not even what freeness means for group actions on a set! Freeness should mean that the quotient $X \to X/G$ exhibits $X$ as a $G$-torsor over $X/G$, or something like that.

This is discussed in Demazure and Gabriel, Groupes algébriques, Tome I (sadly, of I), III, §2, 2.3.  The definition is just as you expect:

Soient $\mathfrak G$ un $k$-foncteur en groupes opérant sur un $k$-foncteur $\mathfrak X_0$ et $\mathfrak X$ le $k$-groupoïde de base $\mathfrak X$ associé (1.3).
On dit que $\mathfrak G$ opère librement sur $\mathfrak X_0$ si, pour tout $R \in \mathsf M_k$, $\mathfrak G(R)$ opère librement sur $\mathfrak X_0(R)$, c'est-à-dire si $g \in \mathfrak G(R)$, $x \in \mathfrak X_0(R)$ et $g x = x$ implique $g = e$.
…
Corollaire.  Soit $\mathfrak G$ un $k$-schéma en groupes localement algébrique opérant sur un $k$-schéma $\mathfrak X_0$.  Pour que $\mathfrak G$ opère librement il faut et il suffit que, pour tout $x \in \mathfrak X_0$, le group d'inertie $\mathfrak G^T(x)$ soit trivial.

In 2.5:

Corollaire.  Supposons que $k$ soit un corps de caractéristique $0$.  Soient $\mathfrak G$ un $k$-groupe localement algébrique opérant sur un $k$-schéma localement algébrique $\mathfrak X_0$, et $\bar k$ une clôture algébrique de $k$.  Pour que $\mathfrak G$ opère librement sur $\mathfrak X_0$, il faut et il suffit que $\mathfrak G(\bar k)$ opère librement sur $\mathfrak X_0(\bar k)$.

In 2.8:

Corollaire.  Supposons que $k$ soit un corps de caractéristique $p \ne 0$.  Soient $\bar k$ un clôture algébrique de $k$ et $\mathfrak G$ un $k$-groupe localement algébrique opérant sur un $k$-schéma localement algébrique $\mathfrak X_0$.  Les assertions suivantes sont équivalentes:
(i) $\mathfrak G$ opère librement sur $\mathfrak X_0$.
(ii) $\mathfrak G(\bar k)$ opère librement sur $\mathfrak X_0(\bar k)$ et, pour tout point fermé $x \in \mathfrak X_0$, l'algèbre d'inertie $(\operatorname{Lie} \mathfrak G)^T(x)$ est nulle.

